# while selecting multiple options from dropdown list in active admin table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

while selecting multiple options from dropdown list in active admin table 
multiple selected items are not showing in index file

```
form do |f|
    inputs 'Contact Group' do    
        #f.input :contact_id, as: :select, collection: Contact.all, multiple: true
        #f.input :contact_id, as: :select, collection: Contact.select(:name).uniq,multiple: true
        f.input :contact_id, as: :select, :collection => Contact.all.collect {|contact| [contact.name, contact.id] }, multiple: true
        f.input :name
        f.input :disable
    end
    actions
  end

  index do
    id_column
    column :contact_id
    column :name
    column :disable
    actions
  end
```

Comment: try `Contact.all.map(|contact| [contact.name, contact.id] )`

Comment: You should just be able to do `:collection => Contact.all` and formtastic will see if `Contact` responds to `:name` and if it does, it'll use that as the label.